# [Qt]Prevent display from turning off due to inactivity when watching full screen video

Tags: c++, windows, qt, video-player

I'm writing some videoplayer based on Gstreamer...
When Application go to full screenmode after some time display goes off...
how modern players not allow sreen to switch off?
and is it possible to hide coursor ?

Comment: I'm quite that will require native API calls

Comment: should read "quite sure"